# Why can only get access video with 127.0.0.1:8081?

Tags: ip, motion

My local pc's address is `192.168.31.167`.

```
sudo ifconfig | grep inet
        inet 192.168.31.167  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.31.255
```

Install motion and start it:

```
sudo apt install motion
sudo motion
```

I can only get access video with `127.0.0.1:8081` in browser.

[image]

Why `192.168.31.167:8081` can't play the video?

Comment: Probably "motion" is configured to listed only the local interface. It is a very sensible default to set. Check the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

To set them off in /etc/motion/motion.conf

```
webcontrol_localhost off
stream_localhost off
```

Comment: If this answers your question, then click the ✓ (maybe you have to wait a day or 2)